# How to overlay two plots using rworldmap?

Tags: r, rworldmap

Hi I want to overlay two world map plots using rworldmap, but the blow code does not work, it only shows map2. Can anyone help me with this please?

```
library(rworldmap)
data(countryExData)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(countryExData
                             , joinCode="ISO3"
                             , nameJoinColumn="ISO3V10")

#map1
mapDevice()
map1 <- mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot='BIODIVERSITY')

#map2
map1 + mapBubbles(sPDF, nameZSize="ECOSYSTEM")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `par(new = TRUE)` after plotting the first map. The second map will then be plotted on top. For details see [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/par).

Updated code:

```
library(rworldmap)
data(countryExData)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(countryExData,
                            joinCode = "ISO3",
                            nameJoinColumn = "ISO3V10")

#map1
mapDevice()
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = 'BIODIVERSITY')

# draw next frame as if it were on a new device
par(new=TRUE)

#map2
mapBubbles(sPDF, nameZSize = "ECOSYSTEM")
```